# Symfony2 - bin/vendors install - Cannot import resource config.yml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony-sonata

Following the [installation instructions](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/installation.html), I added

```
#depts
[SonataAdminBundle]
    git=git://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

And

```
#app/config/config.yml
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
```

Launched the updates

```
$ php bin/vendors install
```

All vendor bundles got updated/installed but after `SonataAdminBundle` it was written

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                 
Cannot import resource "/var/www/Symfony/app/config/config.yml" from "/var/  
www/Symfony/app/config/config_dev.yml".                                      

[InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sonata_block" (in  
/var/www/Symfony/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "sonata_bloc  
k", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctr  
ine", "assetic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "glide_rep  
ort", "fos_user", "glide_user", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distri  
bution"                                                                      

[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                 
Cannot import resource "/var/www/Symfony/app/config/config.yml" from "/var/  
www/Symfony/app/config/config_dev.yml".                                      

[InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sonata_block" (in  
/var/www/Symfony/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "sonata_bloc  
k", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctr  
ine", "assetic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "glide_rep  
ort", "fos_user", "glide_user", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distri  
bution"
```

What can be the cause(s) ?

Comment: Did you register the Bundle to your Kernel? In `AppKernel.php` ? :)

Comment: I will register it when it will be well installed (which I'm trying to do) :)

Comment: Your problem is actually that your bundle isn't registered! You're trying to load configuration associated with a Bundle which is not registered, therefore Loader doesn't know how to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonataAdminBundle has got many dependencies, as it's written in the instructions you referenced. Those are:

```
    SonataCacheBundle
    SonataBlockBundle
    SonatajQueryBundle
    KnpMenuBundle (Version 1.1.*)
    Exporter
```

You probably missed SonataBlockBundle (at least the error shows that you don't have the extension to load `sonata_block` from the config.yml)

Comment: I didn't know we had to manage dependencies manually. I though it were managed in git packages. I'm going to try this way.